# calling drupal webservice to post data from objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, drupal, cookies

I have drupal webservice to post(save) an item through objective c. I googled and found that  I need to set cookie for that. So i did the following:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://lanetteam.net/kaleio/services/session/token"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
NSString* csrf;
csrf = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://lanetteam.net/kaleio/node?title=%@&body[und][0][value]=%@",_txtTitle.text,txtContent.text];

NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request1= [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url1];
NSURLResponse *response1 = nil;
[request1 setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request1 addValue:csrf forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-CSRFToken"];

NSDictionary *properties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"Cookie", NSHTTPCookieName,
                            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", [appDelegate.dictUserProfile valueForKey:@"session_name"],[appDelegate.dictUserProfile valueForKey:@"sessionid"]], NSHTTPCookieValue,
                            nil];
NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:properties]; //**error here, cookie is returned as nil**

NSArray* cookies = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: cookie, nil];



NSDictionary * headers = [NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies:cookies];


[request1 setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];

NSData *responseData1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request1 returningResponse:&response1 error:nil];

NSMutableArray *jsonArray=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData1 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

NSLog(@"data : %@", jsonArray);
```

i have mentioned above where the error occurs. Please let me know how do i solve this, i have been trying this since last many days. Without setting cookie, i get the following error :

```
CSRF validation failed
```

Comment: Hi @Z22 can u get answer of this  I am also suffer same problem since 20days

Comment: can u get answer of this

Answer (score 2):

I am suffer also same problem.After setting a token I am geeting error CSRF validation failed.But i am got solution I think its not appropriate before call any webservices. call logout services it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the X-CSRF-Token and put it in your header.

After logging in, you can get the token from a browser by going to:
http://yoursite.com/services/session/token

Then, put the token in the header of all your requests:

```
X-CSRF-Token=<token>
```

See also:
[How to get CSRF token in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14298044/how-to-get-csrf-token-in-ios)