# iOS/Objective-C - How do I query a web server database from an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, database, service, web

I'm not sure how to run a PHP script from Objective-C to retrieve GET data for querying a database. Is there a way to execute and retrieve returned data from a PHP script directly from Objective-C? Better yet, is there functionality to query a MySQL database server directly from iOS/Objective-C? Any thoughts are appreciated.

Jake

Comment: can you create the php file..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send a Get request in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212453/how-to-send-a-get-request-in-ios)

Comment: @jake Byman- have u heard about xml and Json...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can safely query a mysql database, directly from objective-c.

you must create a php code like this:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("server", "username", "password");
if (!$con)
{
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("username_numberOfTable", $con);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT id, Name, Type FROM table") 
or die ('Query is invalid: ' . mysql_error());

$intNumField = mysql_num_fields($query);
$resultArray = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

$arrCol = array();
for($i=0;$i<$intNumField;$i++)
   {

    $arrCol[mysql_field_name($query,$i)] = $row[$i];

} 

array_push($resultArray,$arrCol);

}

mysql_close($con);

echo json_encode($resultArray);

?>
```

and this is the part of objective-c:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

  NSString *stringName = @"Name";
  NSString *stringType = @"Type";

    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL    URLWithString:@"http://yourURL.php?"]];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest  delegate:self];
 }

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

[receivedData appendData:data];

 }

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

if (receivedData) {

      id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

    for (NSDictionary *dataDict in jsonObjects) {

        NSString *stringNameID = [dataDict objectForKey:@"Name"];
        NSString *stringTypeID = [dataDict objectForKey:@"Type"];


    dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:stringNameID, stringName, stringTypeID, stringType, nil];

        [yourNSMutableArray addObject:dict];


    }

   [self.tableView reloadData];

 }

}


 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

 NSDictionary *tmpDict = [yourNSMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = [tmpDict objectForKey:stringName];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [tmpDict objectForKey:stringType];


 }
```

and that's it, I hope can I help

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you! Additional question: how do you think I should handle running PHP on a server? Must I create my own dedicated server running PHP? You gave the example of "http://yourURL.php?", but realistically how would that URL exist? Do I have to create a web server running PHP simply to query the database? Or is there a way to have that .php file in the iOS project directory such that it can do it directly from the iOS project?

Comment: I bought a server, and a database mysql, after you create a php file and you put it on your server. this php file, it will make the connection between mysql and objective-c. realistically "yourURL.php" could be like: www.yourname.com/yourfile.php.       honestly I never thought to put the php file directly within the app, so I can not tell in this case

Comment: Yeah see that's what I'm wondering. I'm thinking pragmatically maybe it would be more of a hassle to buy a dedicated MySQL server just for a small-mid size iOS app. Plus the database I'm querying isn't even mine! I'm hosting it on an external server, so it would seem to defeat the purpose to buy a server that would query another server!

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of service that can be used to send data to a web server:

1. Synchronous NSURL Request
2. Asynchronous NSURL Request

If you want to only post data to web server then use an asynchronous request because it works in the background and doesn't block the user interface.

```
NSString *content = @"txtfiedl.text=1";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ex.com/yourfile.php"]];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]];

[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```