# How to display Json data in UITableviewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json

And am currently working on `JSON`. i am just using `jsp webserver`. And using JSON data i want to display  in my `uitableviewcell`.I tried some  program.But i have getting some errors.

Here is my `JSON`.

`[{"result":[{"request_id":508,"ticket_number":"PA_1000508","email":"harI","user_id":6,"description":"Feed","createdTime":"10/15/2013 10:52:32 AM","status":"initiated"},{"request_id":507,"ticket_number":"PA_1000507","email":"hari","user_id":6,"description":"","createdTime":"10/15/2013 10:52:16 AM","status":"initiated"},{"request_id":505,"ticket_number":"PA_1000505","email":"hari","user_id":6,"description":"test","createdTime":"10/15/2013 10:42:26 AM","status":"initiated"},{"request_id":504,"ticket_number":"PA_1000504","email":"hari","user_id":6,"description":"desccccccccccccccccccc","createdTime":"10/15/2013 10:42:06 AM","status":"initiated"},`

I want to display the data in my `uitableviewcell`

Here is my sample code.

```
TotalRequest.h

@interface TotalRequests : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
    NSMutableData *data;
    NSArray *listItems;
    NSURLConnection *connection;
    NSString *stat;
    IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;
}

TotalRequest.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.title=@"Total Requests";
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http:sampleurl"];
    NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if(connection)    
    {
        data=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
    data=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchData) 
    withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
}

-(void)fetchData:(NSData *)responseData
{
    NSError *error=nil;
    NSDictionary *json=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData 
    options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSDictionary *tRequest=[json objectForKey:@"userId"];
    NSLog(@"Total Requests :%@",tRequest);
    if(!tRequest)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error In Json :%@",error);
    }
    else
    for(NSDictionary *newValue in tRequest)
    {
        NSString *tNumber=[newValue objectForKey:@"ticket_number"];
        NSString *time=[newValue objectForKey:@"createdTime"];
        stat=[newValue objectForKey:@"status"];
        NSLog(@"ticket_number :%@",tNumber);
        NSLog(@"createdTime :%@",time);
        NSLog(@"status :%@",stat);
    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[[listItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"ticket_number"];
    cell.textLabel.text=[[listItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"createdTime"];
    cell.textLabel.text=[[listItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"status"];
    return cell;
}


-(void)connection :(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    data=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
}


-(void)connection : (NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData
{
    [data appendData:theData];
}

-(void)connection :(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error

{
    NSLog(@"Error in Connection");
}
```

The error message is:

```
-[TotalRequests fetchData]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7162820 15:02:36.685 sampleWebservices[2897:11303]Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TotalRequests fetchData]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7162820' *** First throw call stack: (0x1c99012 0x10d6e7e 0x1d244bd 0x1c88bbc 0x1c8894e 0xb15fb4 0xb15e67 0x3d45 0xfc1c7 0xfc232 0xfc4da 0x1138e5 0x1139cb 0x113c76 0x113d71 0x11489b 0x114e93 0x114a88 0x3607 0xca285 0xca4ed 0xad45b3 0x1c58376 0x1c57e06 0x1c3fa82 0x1c3ef44 0x1c3ee1b 0x1bf37e3 0x1bf3668 0x1affc 0x28bd 0x27e5)
```

Comment: What is your Problem?

Comment: check my answer, the part of objective-c: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108976/ios-objective-c-how-do-i-query-a-web-server-database-from-an-iphone-app/19110548#19110548

Comment: Use debugger to find place of errors if needed. And what are these errors ?

Comment: I Had getting Following error.If i click the Totalrequest cell the following error message will be displayed.

Comment: @murthysurya Please edit your question to display the error message.

Comment: The JSON in your question is malformed. The last "," should be replaced with "]}]"

Answer (score 3):

In TotalRequest.m Replace your code:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchData) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
```

with this:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Please, note that I added ":" to selector(fetchData)

When you use performSelector methods and your method receives a parameter, you have to add ":" to the method name.

**EDIT**

After fixing your first problem, now appears a second one. In your interface declaration you state you implement UITableViewDataSource. If you check apple's documentation( https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html ), you will see there are two required methods:
– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:  required method
– tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:  required method

You implemented the first one, but not the second. It is a method that tells a tableView how many rows there will be in a section. I see your data model is "listItems", so you should add this code to your TotalRequest.m file:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [listItems count];
}
```

I am considering you have only one section. Please adjust the logic of this method if you have different needs.

Comment: sampleWebservices[3169:11303] Error In Json :Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (No value.) UserInfo=0x901d000 {NSDebugDescription=No value.}
2013-10-15 15:49:20.252 sampleWebservices[3169:11303] -[TotalRequests tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7569c10
2013-10-15 15:49:20.274 sampleWebservices[3169:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TotalRequests tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7569c10

Comment: still i had getting the above error if i click the Totalrequestcell

Comment: @murthysurya Please, note the error is different now. It says you are sending the message tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: to your TotalRequests object. I'm editing my answer to help you.

Comment: @murthysurya Are you sure it's the same error? Or is it telling you now "[TotalRequests tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]" ?

Comment: @dude thanks for your response.still getting the error.sampleWebservices[3346:11303] Total Requests :(null)
2013-10-15 16:02:49.091 sampleWebservices[3346:11303] Error In Json :Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (No value.) UserInfo=0x712ef90 {NSDebugDescription=No value.}

Comment: @murthysurya The comments section is not the place to debug your application. You asked a question and it has been answered. If you are facing new problems you should start a new question. This last comment  seems to be a JSON related issue.